# Simple template engine on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, template-engine

I need a good simple template engine for `HTML` on `JS`. I'm looking for a third-party library like jQuery. Or maybe within jQuery already exists any temlate engine? Can advise something?

Comment: Google returns answers to your question when asked about "simple javascript templating engine". Commented comparison of 15 engines is [http://codecondo.com/15-javascript-template-engines](http://codecondo.com/15-javascript-template-engines), selector for 1 of 17 engines is [http://garann.github.io/template-chooser](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good start : https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Another nice one http://handlebarsjs.com/ or http://underscorejs.org/

Templates comparison :

http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more

Comment: 15 Lines only

http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Javascript-template-engine-in-just-20-line

Answer (score 7):

The simplest one is included in [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template) or [lodash.js](http://lodash.com/docs#template)
It works like this

```
var list = "<% _.each(people, function(name) { %> <li><%= name %></li> <% }); %>";

_.template(list, {people: ['moe', 'curly', 'larry']});

// => "<li>moe</li><li>curly</li><li>larry</li>"
```

Apart from templating, underscore is also a great JS utility belt.

Handlebars and Mustache are a bit more complex and allow to build more sophisticated templates.